# Solution to Hyperbolic-type metric on punctured disk

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

How can I solve the for the geodesics of this modified version of the hyperbolic metric inside the closed punctured disc 
$$
\{
(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : 
0<x^2+y^2\leq 1
\}?
$$

$$
ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$

I expect the solutions to be two types of geodesics
- (Very small) arcs 
- movement towards the boundary around and back up (ish)...

How can I prove this?

Comment: This does not define a metric on the disk, because it blows up at the origin.

Comment: Depends...I'm allowing for infinite distance (like disjoint metric spaces)

Comment: Hint: Write your metric in polar coordinates (which will be the universal cover of the punctured disk).

Comment: Perfect, I did that and solved it ...thanks! 
I do have a follow-up question then... if I had the same problem but my domain is a closed punctured simplex and the central point is removed and repels in the same way.... is the problem solvable using similar techniques?

Comment: You would beed to check that  the simplex is convex in this metric, which seems to be OK. Then the same proof goes through.